# how to solve this sqlite3 errror

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working on API development at the flask and stuck on this problem. I don't know what to do. The code is like :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, url_for
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        con = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s AND password = %s',(username,password))
        account = cur.fetchone()

        if account:
            session['logged'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            return "Login Successful"
        else:
            return "Incorrect username/Password!"

    return render_template("login.html", msg=msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

After running and doing the login into the page the main problems comes with

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use prepared statements with sqlite3 you must use `?` as a placeholder for variables in your SQL.

Example:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?', (username,password))
```

Example with named placeholders:

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :username AND password = :password', {'username': username, 'password': password})
```